# Finding the occurrence and position of a character in python

Tags: python, pandas, position, np, find-occurrences

I have a variable (var) with ids
I am interested in finding out the position of last occurrence of Z

I have tried to convert it to an array with their positions

```
    zf1=np.where(df2['Var']=="Z")
```

This will give me the result as

```
    (array([4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,22,23,24,25],dtype=int64),)
```

My idea was to find the difference of these values and look for -1 - I use the index value of this -1 to add an id next to it

```
    np.diff(zf1)


    Var              ID
    A
    B
    C
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z          1
    X
    X
    X
    X
    X
    X
    B
    A
    C
    Z
    Z
    Z
    Z           2
```

np.diff is not giving me -1. Is there any alternate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Get Index values***

```
df2.index[df2.Var.eq('Z') & df2.Var.ne(df2.Var.shift(-1))]
```

***Filter `df2`***

```
df2[df2.Var.eq('Z') & df2.Var.ne(df2.Var.shift(-1))]
```

Comment: Thank you.. but it is giving me the last 'Z' the position. I want both 12th and 25th positions from the above data. Currently it is returning 25

Comment: Thank you.. It really helps !!